# How do I override layouts.xml - Magento 2

Tags: template, overrides, magento2.2, page-layouts

I am trying to override the file `app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layouts.xml`

I do not want to extend this file, I want to override it so that some of the base design layouts are not available in the admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of overriding `layouts.xml` I ended up doing the following

Create a new `Module`: `app/code/<Vendor>/Cms`

Create the file: `app/code/<Vendor>/Cms/Model/PageLayout.php`

```
<?php

namespace <Vendor>\Cms\Model;

use Magento\Cms\Model\Page\Source\PageLayout as BasePageLayout;

class PageLayout extends BasePageLayout{

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = parent::toOptionArray();
        $remove = [
            "empty",
            "1column",
            "2columns-left",
            "2columns-right",
            "3columns",
        ];

        foreach($options as $key => $layout){
            if(in_array($layout["value"], $remove)){
                unset($options[$key]);
            }
        }

        return $options;
    }
}
```

This will get the `$options` and then remove any that are in the `$remove` array based on the `$option['value']`

In order to have this run, you need to override part of `app/code/Magento/Cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml`

To do this create the file: `app/code/<Vendor>/Cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="design">
        <field name="page_layout">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object"><Vendor>\Cms\Model\PageLayout</item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

We are now telling that ui_component field to use our new Model to retrieve the options.

You can also create the file `app/code/<Vendor>/Cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_listing.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="cms_page_columns">
        <column name="page_layout">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object"><Vendor>\Cms\Model\PageLayout</item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your layout file inside "/override/base" folder.

In your case your layout file will be located in "theme_or_module_folder/Magento_Theme/layout/override/base/layouts.xml"

For more information see http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html

Comment: I believe this only overrides files inside `app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layouts/*.xml`. This file is outside of that folder. I tried adding the file as you described and I get the following error: `Overriding view file '/var/www/html/app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/override/base/layouts.xml' does not match to any of the files`

Comment: Can you try to put the file inside the override folder instead of base?

Comment: nope didn't seem to work